# orthogonal and orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Given the vectors $\overrightarrow{a}=\left(2,-2,2\right)$ and $\overrightarrow{b}=\left(4,2,-2\right)$, I have shown that $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ are orthogonal, $a.b=0$
I have then found a general form of vector c which is orthogonal to a and b to be $\overrightarrow{c}=(0, y, y)$

The final part of the questions asks me to derive an orthonormal set of vectors based on $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$ however I am not too sure what this requires me to do?

Comment: Pick unit vectors parallel to $a$ and $b$ and choose $y$ so that $c$ is a unit vector. The three unit vectors you get will be an orthonormal set, because when you replace a set of mutually orthogonal vectors with other vectors respectively parallel to them, the new set of vectors are still mutually orthogonal.

Comment: As far as I can understand, since the 3 vectors are mutually orthogonal, it is just sufficient to divide each vector by its $\ell_2$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\vec c=(x, y, z)$ then for $\vec c$ to be orthogonal to $\vec a=(2, -2, 2)$ & $\vec b=(4, 2, -2)$, one should have  $$\vec a\cdot \vec c=0$$
$$2x-2y+2z=0\ \ or \ \ \ x-y+z=0$$
$$\vec b\cdot \vec c=0$$
$$4x+2y-2z=0\ \ or \ \ \ 2x+y-z=0$$